# Precedence packagingExcludes and packagingIncludes maven war plugin

Tags: java, regex, maven, maven-3, maven-war-plugin

Recently I configured my application to use "skinny wars" that was described on codehaus (title: Solving the skinny war problem). Basically I exclude all jars from the war and add it as a war *and* pom dependency to the ear. Now I ran into a problem with two jars. So to me the logical thing to do was include them in the war file using packagingInclude.

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>
        <packagingIncludes>WEB-INF/lib/A.jar, WEB-INF/lib/B.jar</packagingIncludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Using a regex as showed in de [plugin documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28287967/3100839) but it didn't seem to do anything. It just excludes everyting.

In the [source code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-war-plugin-2.6) of the plugin I found that it uses the DocumentScanner of org.codehaus.plexus » plexus-utils. I didn't quite understand how it works.

I thought this was a no brainer. But what am I doing wrong? Could it be that the inclusion doesn't work when A is also a transitive dependency of C?

Edit: Does plugin version play any role? Now I am using 2.6 but previously version 2.1-alpha-2 was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17175762/maven-packagingexcludes-jars-regex?noredirect=1&lq=1) as well. The following line (and only this line) works:

`<packagingExcludes>%regex[WEB-INF/lib/(?!common-A|common-B).*.jar]</packagingExcludes>`

Only `common-A-x.x.jar` and `common-B-x.x.jar` are in the `WEB-INF/lib`folder of the war file. It should be possible to extract the common part in the regex but what I tried didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the includes only without the wildcard excludes definition. Since you exclude all jars this eats up your includes. As far as I understand the doc (and from my memories), the default is to include everything but as soon as you specify an include the plugin will only include your list of jars.

Comment: You are right, but everything else is excluded as well. So no .jsp etc.

Comment: Ok and how did your exclude regex look like? Maybe it was wrong. I also needed to use regular expressions and it worked fine. But if

Comment: Sorry rest was missing. What I wanted to say is that I would avoid regex if possible since it is not well maintainable. Btw. This whole packaging mechanism of maven is poor and way too complicated.

Comment: I'd like to avoid a regex if it  is possible but at this moment I wouldn't no how. The original questions remains what takes precedence include or exclude and what are the implications of this .