# How can I exclude folders from the WAR?

Tags: java, maven

I tried to follow [Maven packagingExcludes jars regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17175762/maven-packagingexcludes-jars-regex) and this is how my pom.xml file looks. The full path to the node_modules is `project-directory/src/main/webapp/node_modules`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <groupId>mobi.grocerymonkey.groceryapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>groceryapp</artifactId>

  <properties>
    <!-- uncomment if you wish to set your project here project- gcloud is used otherwise -->
    <!-- <app.deploy.project>enduring-trees-259812</app.deploy.project> -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.showDeprecation>true</maven.compiler.showDeprecation>
    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
  </properties>

  <prerequisites>
    <maven>3.5</maven>
  </prerequisites>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.59</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.59</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-tools-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.59</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.truth</groupId>
      <artifactId>truth</artifactId>
      <version>0.33</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.2-beta</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
      <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <!-- for hot reload of the web application-->
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <project>enduring-trees-259812</project>
          <version>1</version>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
              <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api</exclude>
            <exclude>com.google.guava:guava</exclude> <!-- avoid android version -->
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <packagingExcludes>
            %regex[node_modules]
          </packagingExcludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.20</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
      </plugin>

            <!-- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/building-app/environment-setup //-->
            <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
            <jvmFlags>
              <jvmFlag>-Xdebug</jvmFlag>
              <jvmFlag>-Dappengine.fullscan.seconds=1</jvmFlag>
            </jvmFlags>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-maven</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireMavenVersion>
                  <version>3.5</version>
                </requireMavenVersion>
                <requirePluginVersions>
                   <message>Best Practice is to always define plugin versions!</message>
                   <banLatest>true</banLatest>
                   <banRelease>true</banRelease>
                   <phases>clean,deploy,verify,appengine:run,appengine:deploy,appengine:update,appengine:devappaserver,site</phases>
                </requirePluginVersions>
              </rules>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I added the following to exclude the nodes_modules folder but I still see that my build includes it and generating it, takes several minutes (Total time:  03:16 min)

```
<packagingExcludes>
                %regex[node_modules]
              </packagingExcludes>
```

How do I exclude the node_modules from my war file?

Comment: where is node_modules folder.. please mention the path of the folder you want to exclude.

Answer (score 0):

you're using `regex` version of `packagingExcludes` which is not the use case of yours. Try to specify folder path specified [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html)  as follows

```
<packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/node_modules/**</packagingExcludes>    <!--or correct path to your folder-->
```